# PDF to Text file conversion

Tags: r, text-mining

I have 3000 sub folder in one main folder containing 2 pdfs in each. 
I wrote the following code to convert PDFs in Text file.

*all.subfolders <- list.dirs("# Path to main folder", full.names = TRUE)

```
sapply(all.subfolders[-1], function(x) {

file <-list.files(x, full.names=TRUE)

lapply(file, function(x) system(paste('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\xpdfbin-win-3.03\\bin64\\pdftotext.exe"', paste0('"', x, '"')), wait = FALSE))})*
```

But there in few PDFs which could not be converted in Text, How to get them in one list or so. 
Please help.

Comment: Why couldn't these pdfs be converted? Did you get an error message? Maybe these PDFs don't contain text?

Comment: They contain text but I think that PDFs are scanned ones so couldn't converted. I dint get any error message. After executing commands, i dint find their converted file in respective folder.

Answer (score 0):

My reputations is not high enough for commenting, so please excuse me for making this an answer, which it is not. Your pdf files are probably protected, so that the text cannot be extracted. Try copying text from these documents when you open them with a pdf Viewer. This will probably not work either due to the protection. In case you have the permission to extract and process the text, you might consider to convert the files to images, e.g., via ImageMagick, and apply OCR, e.g., via tesseract, on the images. To get started you might refer, e.g., to the following script https://gist.github.com/benmarwick/11333467.

In response to your comment regarding how to identify the files that have not been converted, you might use the following approach. I hope this is what you have been looking for.

```
#retrieve all file paths
#note that you can use recursive = T to avoid looping over directories yourself
allfiles <- list.files("C:/.../mydirectory", full.names = T, recursive = T)

#split filepaths into a set of pdf and txt files
#txt files will, of course, only be the files that have been converted
pdffiles <- allfiles[grep("pdf$", allfiles)]
txtfiles <- allfiles[grep("txt$", allfiles)]

#remove file ending
pdffiles <- gsub(".pdf", "", pdffiles)
pdffiles <- gsub(".txt", "", pdffiles)

#check which files have not been converted
notconverted <- setdiff(pdffiles, txtfiles)

#if needed, file ending can be added again
#e.g. for copying the unconverted files into a separate directory or so
notconverted <- paste0(pdffiles, ".pdf")
```

Comment: The immediate problem is to find those unconverted PDFs / sub folder... I have 3000 sub folders so manually its not possible to check each folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and code. It solved the problem of locating unconverted files. Thank You

Comment: I am glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer to close this thread.